# wso2 identity server 5.4 Google as IdP

Tags: oauth, saml, idp, wso2-identity-server

We've populated a test google instance with user data such as externalIds that are unique to our institution - see https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource

We have wso2 server 5.4 and are exploring using Google as our IdP.  However, we are a bit new to SAML/Oauth/OpenId, etc, and are just beginning to learn about them in depth.

We've successfully connected Google to wso2 as an Identity Provider using Federated Authenticators.

However, when we use that IdP for an SP (saml or oauth), it only returns a default set of information about the user.  How can we return more profile information that is stored in Google?

I've been reading about scopes and claims and, etc.. but I'm not connecting the dots so far.

If I populate "customerId" in the Google Directory using their API for all our users, how can I get wso2 to return that information to the SP?

Comment: If we federate with Google, what is the underlying connection to them?  OpenID? Oauth?  Because it seems like many of the user fields in Google are not available depending on how you connect to Google as your IdP.

Comment: If we federate with Google, what is the underlying connection to them?  OpenID? Oauth?  Because it seems like many of the user fields in Google are not available depending on how you connect to Google as your IdP.     In the custom dialect area of the claim mappings in the Federated Google IdP, it wants the "Identity Provider Claim URI".    Searching for that terminology on Google doesn't return any hits.  The best I've found so far refers to 'scopes'.     Can you point me to a list of Google claim URI's?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wso2 claim handing to achieve it. When configuring IDP, in the "Basic Claim Configuration" you can enable "Define Custom Claim Dialect". Then add claim map "customerId" to a wso2 local claim(http://wso2.org/claims/userid). In the SP configurations' "Claim Configuration", you have to add that particular claim(http://wso2.org/claims/userid) to the requested claim.